# In excel, how do I sort by one column but keep all adjacent columns also fixed to it?

Tags: excel

I have a relatively simple excel issue, but I can't seem to get it working.

Here is my chunk of spreadsheet :

[image]

For some reason, when I sort by "Resource" column(ascending), it only will sort the resource column. But all the others columns( Dev ID#, INT481 Development, etc), stay exactly the same. I want to have all other columns shift positions also.

Does this have to do with any formulas, possibly? Because if I do a vanilla 2-column table in another spreadsheet, then it keeps both columns fixed together when I do the same sort. But here, it only sorts the Resource columns, but the others stay the same.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a hidden column between the resource column and the rest of the table? If you do, and it has empty values, then Excel has trouble determining what to include in the sort unless you specifically select the whole table manually first.

From your screenshot you appear to have only applied the filter/sort to the resource column. You need to select the entire table before you tell Excel to sort (it will ask which column(s) you want to sort by if there's more than one, and you can even line up several conditions in the order of your preference, e.g. sort by Column E, A-Z, then by Column A, Z-A, and so on).